# Why does cloning the last element not work in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I try to clone the last row of my table after clicking on the save button. But simply does not clone and append a new row.

What it should do: Click on save -> append a `<tr class="spacer">` and a new `<tr class="tr-shadow">`.
Screenshot:
[image]

My code:

```
                                            ... <tr class="tr-shadow">
                                            <td><select name='weekday[]'>
                                                    <option value='0' selected hidden disabled>Auswählen</option>
                                                    <option value='1'>Montag</option>
                                                    <option value='2'>Dienstag</option>
                                                    <option value='3'>Mittwoch</option>
                                                    <option value='4'>Donnerstag</option>
                                                    <option value='5'>Freitag</option>
                                                    <option value='6'>Samstag</option>
                                                    <option value='7'>Sonntag</option></select></td>
                                            <td><input type="text" name="title[]" placeholder="Title"></td>
                                            <td><select name='rythm[]'>
                                                    <option value='1'>jede Woche</option>
                                                    <option value='2'>nur erster des Monats</option></select></td>
                                            <td><input type="time" name="time[]" placeholder="08:00" required></td>
                                        </tr><tr class="spacer"></tr>
                                    </tbody>

                                </table>
                                <br><input type="submit" id="date-submit" class="au-btn au-btn-icon au-btn--green au-btn--big" value="Save">
```

And my jQuery:

```
                             <script> 
$("#date-submit").click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    //$('#dates .tr-shadow').eq(-1).after('<tr class="spacer">');
    $("#dates .tr-shadow:last").clone().add("#dates .tr-spacer:last");

    request = $.ajax({
    url: "./termin-update.php",
    type: "post",
    data: $("#entrydates").serialize(),
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        snackbar('Error','error');
    },
    success: function (response) {
        snackbar('Successfully saved','success');
    }

    });
});
        </script>
```

Comment: You don't have `tr-spacer` class anywhere. You just have `spacer`...

Comment: @trincot Oh, another mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a clone but not storing a reference to it or chaining an insertion method to it....in other words doing nothing with the clone

Try something like:

```
$('#myTable tbody')
    // append a new row clone
    .append($("#dates .tr-shadow:last").clone())
    // append another spacer after the clone
    .append('<tr class="spacer">')
```

Comment: This works for me, thanks a lot!
But append does mean for me that the line gets inserted after the tbody ... but why is this happening before the tbody? Sorry for asking this dumb question.

Comment: `append()` will insert as last row inside the `<tbody>` not after it

Comment: Okay, thanks! But the next problem is now, that with clicking on "Save" the data from above and the last new row is submitted, but not the cloned elements (the user should continuously add new dates and with clicking on "Save" he should get a new line for an input). Do you maybe have an idea for that?

Comment: You are using `[]` in the names of form controls so no I don't know why that is happening.

Comment: Mhm, I hope I get this fixed, otherwise this was useless for me ... seems like serialize does not "take" the cloned elements ...

Comment: Try inspecting what is actually sent using browser dev tools -> Network then open the atual request and look at paramaters

Comment: I did this right now and yes, indeed, serialize does not take the cloned elements. Only the rows above and my hardcoded new line.

Comment: Can you make a demo in jsfiddle that ignores the ajax but logs the serialize string?